Show both up and down sorting arrows for Angular material table using mat-sort (Angular material 17)
I am trying to show both the ascending and descending arrows for an unsorted column.

.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  opacity: 0.54 !important;
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}

.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-indicator {
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-pointer-left {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-pointer-right {
  transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
}


This is my current css which just shows the single arrow


The below CSS might help you, we use the pseudo selectors :after to display the icon with the content set as '↑↓'
.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted):after {
  content: '↑↓';
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}

.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-indicator {
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-pointer-left {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted)
  .mat-sort-header-pointer-right {
  transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo
